# Global Namespace Javascript Error

Tags: javascript, namespaces, global

```
var NS = NS|{};  
NS.A = {
prop1: 'hello',
prop2: 'there',
func: function() {alert('boo');}  
}; 
NS.A.func()
```

The above code gives NS.A is undefined error. 
If I declare NS as below it works

```
var NS = {};
```

Help me understand why.I am trying to use global namespace as defined in 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This actually should work, you just have a typo in the first line.

You have: `var NS = NS|{};`

You should have: `var NS = NS||{};`

[This article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) explains this kind of evaluation

Comment: var NS = NS || {}; Works but lets say we have var NS = SS || {}; where SS is undefined. The expression evaluates to error as SS is undefined. In the first statement NS is also undefined before the expression evaluates but it does not throw error as it is part of declaration?